# How to pass remote_user name and password from a file using Ansible vault

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie in Ansible. Can someone please help me by providing a solution to the below requirement?

I have the below Playbook and inventory file.

Playbook :

```
-
  name: Sample playbook
  hosts: remotehosts
  remote_user: tom
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Ensure directory is present in remote hosts 
    file: path=/usr/local/tom_dir state=directory

  - name: Copy the script to the remote hosts
    copy: src=sample_check.sh dest=/usr/local/tom_dir mode=0755
```

Inventory file :

```
[remotehosts]
server1.host.com
server2.host.com
```

I am able to execute the Playbook using the below command successfully in which I need to provide the remote user SSH password and SUDO password[defaults to SSH password].

```
ansible-playbook  -i inventory.ini sample_playbook.yml -k -K
```

How can I convert the playbook to use Ansible vault to pass the credentials securely? So that it will not ask for the SSH/sudo credentials while executing the Playbook each time.

Comment: Put your ansible_password and ansible_become_password in your inventory for group and/or hosts. Either encrypt the password itselft or the entire file containing it using ansible-vault (see encrypt_string or encrypt). Provide the vault password to your ansible command in either way you wish. For more information: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-vault.html and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: `-k` == `ansible_password`, `-K` == `ansible_become_password`. As described in [_Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters)